# How to make a div change in real time?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm new at Ajax and this code should change the `div` dynamically in real time when the user type something in the input field but nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

    <!--api to use ajax-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sarissa/gr/abiss/js/sarissa/sarissa.js"> </script>
    <title>Ajax Test</title>

    <script>
        function loadXMLDoc() {

            var xmlhttp;
            //parameter
            var suggest = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;

            //using XMLHttpRequest
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            //when xmlhttp be ready...
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    //the HTML will be modify
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            //the file that will receive and retrieve info
            xmlhttp.open("POST","enviar.php",true);

            //header to the retrieved information
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            //the param will be send
            var sendParam = "fname="+suggest;
            xmlhttp.send(sendParam);
        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
Busca: <input type="text" id="searchbox" />
<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onkeypress="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First thing you're going to want to do is use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), specifically, the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function. It'll cut your number of lines down by about half.

Comment: The problem might be from the PHP code, can you show us that/

Comment: Which browser are you using? First step should be to check the console in Firebug (firefox extension) or the developer tools in IE or Chrome. I don't see anything obvious, but it could be a javascript error. (Firebug will also let you see the AJAX call and response).

Answer (score 1):

Change the `onkeypress` event to `onclick`.

If you would like the content to change as the user types, add an `onkeyup` event to the text input element.

Answer (score 0):

First you should put your javascript codes before, your HTML inputs, because, the DOM needs to load the entire document, before it can manupilate it. otherwise, you should put your functions inside the body tag, with onload attribute.

second, use the onclick event instead of onkeypress, I modified your script, and tested it. It works now

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

 Busca: <input type="text" id="searchbox" />
 <div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
 <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

 <script type='text/javascript'>
        function loadXMLDoc() {
            var xmlhttp;
            //using XMLHttpRequest
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            //when xmlhttp be ready...
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    //the HTML will be modify
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

                        //parameter
            var suggest = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;


               var sendParam = "fname="+suggest;
            //the file that will receive and retrieve info
            xmlhttp.open("POST","enviar.php",true);

            //header to the retrieved information
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            //the param will be send

            xmlhttp.send(sendParam);
            console.log(xmlhttp);
        }

</script>

<body/>
```